# Is there an explode function equivalent in plain Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to look for explode function or its equivalent in plain scala rather Spark.
Using the explode function in Spark, I was able to flatten a row with multiple elements into multiple rows as below.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode

scala> val test = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("""{"a":1,"b":[2,3]}""")))

scala> test.schema
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(a,LongType,true), StructField(b,ArrayType(LongType,true),true))

scala> test.show
+---+------+
|  a|     b|
+---+------+
|  1|[2, 3]|
+---+------+

scala> val flat = test.withColumn("b",explode($"b"))
flat: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: bigint, b: bigint]

scala> flat.show
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
+---+---+
```

Is there an explode equivalent function in plain scala without using Spark ? Is there anyway I can implement it if there is no explode function available in scala ?

Comment: What non-Spark data structure are you trying to "explode" with non-Spark code?

Comment: I tried to use a Tuple in scala:
scala> val a = (("a",1),("b",2,3))
But I couldn't come up with a logic that dynamically converts multiple comma seperated values in a tuple's second index into multiple seperate rows.

Comment: The code to explode the tuple you've described would be easy but, because a tuple's type is directly related to its length, that code couldn't handle any tuple type except `TUPLE2[TUPLE2[String,Int],TUPLE3[String,Int,Int]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple `flatMap` should help you in this case. I don't know exact data structure, which you would like to work with in scala, but let's take a bit artificial example:

```
val l: List[(Int, List[Int])] = List(1 -> List(2, 3))
val result: List[(Int, Int)] = l.flatMap {
  case (a, b) => b.map(i => a -> i)
}
println(result)
```

Which will produce next result:

```
List((1,2), (1,3))
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested in comment section by @jwvh, or same result may be achieved using `for-comprehension` construction and hiding explicit `flatMap` & `map` invocations:

```
val result2: List[(Int, Int)] = for((a, bList) <- l; b <- bList) yield a -> b
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: A `map()` inside a `flatMap()`? That's what our friend the `for` comprehension was made for: `for {(k, ls) <- l; v <- ls} yield (k,v)`

Comment: @jwvh Thank you absolutely correct, but my initial intent was to show `flatMap` explicit usage and not hide via `for-comprehension` construction.  But, I'll post an update. Thanks again.

Comment: **For comprehensions** are usually multi line. To make them more readable.

Comment: Also be aware (if you care) that if you destructure in a `<-` generator then an extra `withFilter` call will be added even it's statically provable that the destructuring will never fail. Unless you're using the `better-monadic-for` compiler plugin.